# xml unserialize php pear attributes

Tags: php, xml, serialization, pear

I'm using Pear Serializer to Unserialize this xml

```
<Response Version="3">
<RespClientID>
    <DID>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</DID>
    <ClientRef>XXXXXXXXXXXX</ClientRef>
</RespClientID>
<Status StatusCode="OK"/>
<RegistrationResponse>
    <DID>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</DID>
    <URL>https://.....</URL>
    <URL>https://.....</URL>
</RegistrationResponse>
```

How do I get StatusCode in Status tag?

And this is my code:

```
$registration = registration();
$options = array(
    XML_UNSERIALIZER_OPTION_COMPLEXTYPE => 'object',
    XML_UNSERIALIZER_OPTION_ATTRIBUTE_CLASS => '_classname'
);
$unserializer = new XML_Unserializer($options);
$result = $unserializer->unserialize($registration);
if($result) {
    $data = $unserializer->getUnserializedData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation. [Pear unserializer options](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.xml.xml-serializer.xml-unserializer.options.php)

It looks to me like you need to add `_ATTRIBUTES_PARSE => TRUE` to your `$options` array.

You might also be interested in the `_ATTRIBUTES_ARRAYKEY` and `_ATTRIBUTES_PREPEND` options, depending on how you want the object created.